# How to add prefix in TextInput - React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, textinput

I want to add prefix to my text input and I would like to know how to do it.

**Text Input Code**

```
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputs}
          placeholder="Mobile Number"
          keyboardType="number-pad"
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          onChangeText={mobile_number => this.setState({mobile_number})}
        />
```

Final output I want

[image: ve]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.prefix}>+94</Text>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Mobile Number"
          keyboardType="number-pad"
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          onChangeText={mobile_number => this.setState({ mobile_number })}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inputContainer: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    borderRadius: 10
  },
  prefix: {
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'black'
  }
})
```

[image]

Comment: Thank your for the answer !

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the prefix to be editable, use a label:

```
<View>
  <Label />
  <TextInput />
<View>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a text mask. Try this 
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-text-input-mask

To handle phone number inputs 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-number-input

Answer (score 1):

You can do it combination of two textinput. One is for prefix and other is for input text.
like this:

```
<View>
  <TextInput /> // Text or dropdown pick, something else
  <TextInput />
<View>
```