# How to keep default text value not deleted - React Native Text Input

Tags: android, react-native, textinput, iso

I need to keep +65 as default value and user cannot delete +65 from TextInput and user can input their mobile number as they wish (Please refer screenshot also).

Im Using TextInput component

```
const [phoneNumberText, setPhoneNumberText] = useState('+65');

<TextInput
        keyboardType="numeric"
        value={phoneNumberText}
        onChangeText={(text) => {
          const newPhone = text.replace(/^0+/, '');
          setPhoneNumber(newPhone.replace(/ /g, '').replace('+', ''));
          setPhoneNumberText(newPhone);
        }}
        autoFocus
        style={styles.inputBg}
        underlineColor="#f277c6"
        theme={{
          colors: {
            placeholder: '#B2B4B8',
            text: '#394452',
            primary: '#f277c6',
            underlineColor: '#f277c6',
          },
        }}
        returnKeyType="done"
      />
```

[image]

Comment: you have to set a prefix for your text view. try with this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58707433/how-to-add-prefix-in-textinput-react-native

Comment: @PaolinoLAngeletti that's also my question btw

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found the answer to this without creating a separate label prefix.

Code

```
        <TextInput
            keyboardType="numeric"
            value={phoneNumberText}
            onChangeText={(text) => {
              if (text.startsWith('+65')) {
                const newPhone = text.replace(/^0+/, '');
                setPhoneNumber(newPhone.replace(/ /g, '').replace('+', ''));
                setPhoneNumberText(newPhone);
              }
            }}
            autoFocus
            style={styles.inputBg}
            underlineColor="#f277c6"
            theme={{
              colors: {
                placeholder: '#B2B4B8',
                text: '#394452',
                primary: '#f277c6',
                underlineColor: '#f277c6',
              },
            }}
            returnKeyType="done"
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to not be able to delete the first values ​​of the phone in TextInput, then try this:

```
const [phoneNumberText, setPhoneNumberText] = useState('+65');

 <TextInput
    keyboardType="numeric"
    value={phoneNumberText}
    onChangeText={(text) => {
      if(text.length < 4 ){
        text = phoneNumberText
      }
      const newPhone = text.replace(/^0+/, '');
      setPhoneNumber(newPhone.replace(/ /g, '').replace('+', ''));
      setPhoneNumberText(newPhone);
    }}
    autoFocus
    style={styles.inputBg}
    underlineColor="#f277c6"
    theme={{
      colors: {
        placeholder: '#B2B4B8',
        text: '#394452',
        primary: '#f277c6',
        underlineColor: '#f277c6',
      },
    }}
    returnKeyType="done"
  />
```